# Joins and Aggregates in Javascript Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, linq.js

I have been trying for hours to do this using json.js but is just too much for something that seems simple.  I have this example data:

```
    var hotels = [
        { id: 101, Name: "Hotel 101", WebFacilities: [8, 9, 10] },
        { id: 102, Name: "Hotel 101", WebFacilities: [8] },
        { id: 103, Name: "Hotel 101", WebFacilities: [8, 10] }
    ];

    var facilities = [
        { id: 8, Name: "Facility 8" },
        { id: 9, Name: "Facility 9" },
        { id: 10, Name: "Facility 10" }
    ];
```

I want to get this:

```
    var selectedFacilities = [
        { id: 8, Name: "Facility 8", Count: 3 },
        { id: 9, Name: "Facility 9", Count: 1 },
        { id: 10, Name: "Facility 10", Count: 2 }
    ];
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears you're trying to count how many of each facility there is.

Here's one way to write the query using C#:

```cs
var hotelFacilities =
    from hotel in hotels
    from id in hotel.WebFacilities
    group id by id;

var query =
    from facility in facilities
    join g in hotelFacilities on facility.id equals g.Key
    select new
    {
        id = facility.id,
        Name = facility.Name,
        Count = g.Count(),
    };
```

Now if you can picture this using the method syntax, it is almost a 1:1 transformation to the linq.js version.

Note the way the compiler translates the above will usually include the `GroupBy()` call within the previous `SelectMany()` call. However written this way will make writing the linq.js equivalent query easier and less awkward.

```cs
var hotelFacilities = hotels
    .SelectMany(hotel => hotel.WebFacilities)
    .GroupBy(id => id);

var query = facilities
    .Join(
        hotelFacilities,
        facility => facility.id,
        g => g.Key,
        (facility, g) => new
        {
            id = facility.id,
            Name = facility.Name,
            Count = g.Count(),
        }
    );
```

And the equivalent linq.js query.

```js
var hotelFacilities = Enumerable.From(hotels)
    .SelectMany("hotel => hotel.WebFacilities")
    .GroupBy("id => id")
    .ToArray();

var query = Enumerable.From(facilities)
    .Join(
        hotelFacilities,
        "facility => facility.id",
        "g => g.Key()",
        "(facility, g) => { id: facility.id, Name: facility.Name, Count: g.Count() }"
    ).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var selectedFacilities = facilities;

for(var i = 0; i < facilities.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < hotels.length; j++) {
        if(hotels[j]["id"] == facilities[i]["id"]) {
            // Add data
            selectedFacilities[i]["Count"] = hotels[i]["WebFacilities"].length;
        } else {
            selectedFacilities[i]["Count"] = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem right. I think it was my mistake for not making clear. The idea is to get the number of hotels for each facility. I have updated the ids so it is more clear